# Invalid paths of Stylesheet and Javascript in WordPress (Redux framework themes) when hosted on openshift

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, openshift-origin

The theme options panel does not load correctly with certain themes on OpenShift. I am using Avada theme of wordpress that is built using Redux framework. Everything works perfect on localhost but when I host the site on openshift, the "theme options" doesn't work and FireBug's console shows that the stylesheet and  script paths are messed up by openshift.

The current (invalid) url for an example stylesheet is like this:

**https://my-website.com/wp-content/var/lib/openshift/5942968f‌​2d527198350000f2/app‌​-root/data/themes/th‌​emeName/includes/lib‌​/inc/redux/framework‌​/FusionReduxCore/inc‌​/extensions/import_e‌​xport/import_export/‌​field_import_export.‌​css**

While it should be this:

**https://my-website.com/wp-content/themes/themeName/includes/‌​lib/inc/redux/framew‌​ork/FusionReduxCore/‌​inc/extensions/impor‌​t_export/import_expo‌​rt/field_import_expo‌​rt.css**

there should not be any /var/lib/openshift/ in entire url

I need to get this fixed but I dont know anything about coding in Redux framework and have no idea how to change the path and point it to right path.

Comment: Can you give us more details as of how URLs are defined in your case and what should their path be looking like?

Comment: The current (invalid) url for an example stylesheet is like this:  
**`https://my-website.com/wp-content/var/lib/openshift/5942968f2d527198350000f2/app-root/data/themes/themeName/includes/lib/inc/redux/framework/FusionReduxCore/inc/extensions/import_export/import_export/field_import_export.css`**  
    
While it should be this:  
**`https://my-website.com/wp-content/themes/themeName/includes/lib/inc/redux/framework/FusionReduxCore/inc/extensions/import_export/import_export/field_import_export.css`**    



there should not be any **/var/lib/openshift/** in entire url

Comment: I understand now how your URLs look like and how should they look like. Now, the next question is: How are your URLs being generated? If you search for field_import_export in the whole project, you should be able to find out how its URL is being generated (what is the function call and/or the path in the src attribute)

Comment: In which file to look for that?

Comment: I searched google and its related to something called symmlinks?

could it be `plugin_dir`?

Am blank in all this..specially wordpress coding

Comment: You will need to search for all the occurrences of that text inside your project. The findings, if any will be very good pointers to the problem you have.

Comment: can you plz look into code and try to resolve the problem if i give you access to files?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147259/discussion-between-kavish-mittal-and-lajos-arpad).

Comment: @KavishMittal t is a well know issue. Hope my answer help you. Check the plugin from hit.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue reported
[Here](https://github.com/reduxframework/redux-framework/issues/3054)<sup>1</sup>, [here](https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/wordpress-example/issues/87)<sup>2</sup>,  [here](https://github.com/reduxframework/redux-framework/issues/2398)<sup>3</sup>, [here](https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/wordpress-example/issues/30)<sup>4</sup>and so on.

This is not an issue with Redux.

This happens with theme

You have to contact the theme developer in order to fix this issue.

But there are solutions for to issues I posted above you can check it.

Anyway, I would like to post some fixes in the issues here

Quoting from [WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories)

> It's also important to note that PHP's **FILE** magic-constant resolves symlinks automatically, so if the wp-content or wp-content/plugins or even the individual plugin directory is symlinked, this function will not work corrrectly.

The theme link is symlinked. It is the issue.

A sample fix can be found [here](https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/wordpress-example/commit/634088301dc9bbe07cdbfbed7ae054a4014cfef6)

Another one
 Quoting from [@Liggitt](https://github.com/liggitt)

> Wordpress provides hooks to filter the plugin path. I wrote a simple plugin that will adjust the plugin url to be correct, even when a symlinked folder is used.
>   ssh into your wordpress application, and run the following:

```
cd app-root/data/plugins/
git clone git://github.com/liggitt/wordpress-plugin-symlink.git
```

Log into your wordpress admin console, and activate the plugin-symlink plugin.

Comment: "A sample fix can be found [here](https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/wordpress-example/commit/634088301dc9bbe07cdbfbed7ae054a4014cfef6)"

didnt work at all.

Comment: please add more details then. Theme name, developer name, etc.

Answer (score 1):

[Avada is a paid theme](https://theme-fusion.com/themes/). When paid theme not working, developer should help you. It is purely related to that Theme, neither OpenShift nor core functions of WordPress. Newer WordPress supports different types of hosting and [WordPress doc does have reference when URLs may be not like common traditional hosting](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Additional_Defined_Constants).

I am giving an easy generic fix to load CSS at frontend. That plugin-symlink plugin offered by Sagar V is also generic. That is maximum we can do. You can try to find experienced Avada theme users.

**Dependencies**

Make sure that any dependency Wordpress plugin required by the theme is missing. [Make sure that you have followed the guide of using Redux framework](https://github.com/reduxframework/redux-framework) or [that theme's official docs](https://theme-fusion.com/knowledgebase/avada-v4-migration/).

**Examine how the links being generated**

[This is my 6 years old demo WordPress running on free Openshift with default WordPress theme without any issue](http://thecustomizewindows-abhishekghosh.rhcloud.com). That theme's header file is finding `html5.js` by :

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

To find it, I went to `Appearance > Editor > Theme Header (header.php)` from WordPress admin. Lajos Arpad was asking you that via comments. The correct way is to modify that code. He/She was saying `How are your URLs being generated?` as we lack idea about which files, how generating the links. `header.php` does for common themes but Redux framework themes may do it differently. Lajos Arpad already suggested you to search for field_import_export in the whole project via comments.

**Generic fix**

However we have no code. We need a generic fix. It is a temporary fix for the frontend. You need this at front end :

```
https://my-website.com/wp-content/wp-cntent/themes/th‌​emeName/includes/lib‌​/inc/redux/framework‌​/FusionReduxCore/inc‌​/extensions/import_e‌​xport/import_export/‌​field_import_export.‌​css
```

Make sure it is present, not 404. Install [Header & Footer like plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/header-footer/). Inject the CSS at frontend via that plugin :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://my-website.com/wp-content/wp-cntent/themes/th‌​emeName/includes/lib‌​/inc/redux/framework‌​/FusionReduxCore/inc‌​/extensions/import_e‌​xport/import_export/‌​field_import_export.‌​css"  type="text/css">
```

Comment out the lines injecting CSS, Js in theme's header file or where it is being calling. Load and test. The fix will not suppress any warning but frontend will have loaded on frontend.

Answer (score 1):

Try dropping this into functions.php

```
function ReduxSymLinkURL(){
  $url = "https://my-website.com/wp-content/themes/themeName/includes/‌​lib/inc/redux/framew‌​ork/FusionReduxCore/‌​";
  return $url;
}
add_filter( 'redux/_url', 'ReduxSymLinkURL', 10 );
```

Comment: will give it a try and let you know.